# sudo apt-get update Archives directory is missing

Tags: apt, update, raspbian-wheezy

I have no idea what this means.  Was just doing a routine update on my Raspberry Pi:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get update
E: Archives directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing. - Acquire (5: Input/output error)
```

I have no idea what this means.

Currently running Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Who cares? There is **NO POINT** doing updates on an obsolete, unsupported OS.

Comment: So you are recommending I update to Jessie or whatever then?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using Wheezy if you have some reason. If you are going to "update" don't use Jessie, which is also unsupported, although it still probably gets security updates. NOTE you need to do a fresh install, there is no (supported) upgrade path.

Comment: Thanks.  You're right.  It's been a few years since I last booted this thing up.  Anyone know a good guide for extracting important user data before I wipe it?

Comment: Just two days ago I upgraded Jessie to Ascii (I'm on Devuan), just by changing the entries in /etc/apt/source.list and then the necessary apt-get update, upgrade, dist-upgrade.  Quite confident this would go as smoothly for Jessie to Wheezy.  Only problem was some stuff I had from deb-multimedia.  With Ascii I didn't need those anymore.

Comment: @Bill Do you seriously not understand what "directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial is missing" means?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, every error has a cause and some have implications so it's good to try to understand those rather than just treating the symptom. I am not expert enough on this OS to know if a missing directory here or there is a minor concern or a serious fault. That's why I came to this forum to get help.  Most of the advice here has been very helpful, suggesting that I call it quits and upgrade to the latest OS. Until I read this I wasn't even aware of the difference between update and upgrade and that I needed to do a fresh install - I was expecting the update command to upgrade to latest.

Comment: I'd give an upgrade a try.  If it works, you'll have won a lot of time.  BTW, no one addressed the cause of your problem.  I think someone messed with with /var/cache/apt/archives, perhaps someone needing space.  Someone, not something.

Answer (score 0):

Al you have to do is

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/cache/apt/archives/partial
```